# Cloudfoundry [Cloudfoundry] File.open ruby rails resque class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io, cloud-foundry

I am using cloudfoundry. I upload a file and save the file..my routine returns the path and filename

/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/Dwarfquery-0-99065f0be8880d91916257931ed91162/app/tmp/region1-legends10-11-2012-20:53.xml

However the scheduled resque routine which tries to read it using File.Open returns the following error

Errno::ENOENT
Error
No such file or directory - /var/vcap/data/dea/apps/Dwarfquery-0-99065f0be8880d91916257931ed91162/app/tmp/region1-legends10-11-2012-20:53.xml

This is the path returned by the Upload Server...I have added require 'open-uri' at the top of my Job Class

The line that is failing is

File.open(fpath, 'r+') do |f|

where fpath the the file/directory returning the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not proficient with ruby at all, but just to clarify:

- Are the bit that uploads and the Resque routine part of the same "app" (in Cloud Foundry sense?)
- Are you trying to read the file soon after it has been uploaded, or long after (in particular, after your app has/could have been restarted?)

This is important because:

1. Each "app" has its own temporary folder and obviously one app can't access another app's filesystem. This also holds if you deployed your app with multiple "instances". Each instance is a separate process that has its own filesystem.
2. local filesystem storage is ephemeral and is wiped clean every time the app restarts

If you need to access binary data between apps, you will want to use some kind of storage (e.g. Mongo's GridFS) to have it persisted and visible by both apps.

Comment: The bit that uploads it is the ruby rails server application. This kicks off a resque routine which will then parse the 150 meg odd XML file and pop database. However this resque worker is another application maybe....redis is a service of the main app but the worker command is a standalone application. I don't think cloudfoundry allowsnthe worker to be The same instance as the server app

Comment: Also it seems a bit strange that cloudfoundry allows u to have a redis service bit the workers created off that cannot read the files from the redis server application

Comment: Looks like Dropbox maybe a solution.. Looks like reading the following will help. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#ruby. No confirmation of it working on cloudfoundry though. No confirmation if it works on cloudfoundry

Comment: Dropbox worked  !!!   session = DropboxSession.new(DROPCONFIG['app_key'], DROPCONFIG['app_secret'])
           logger.debug "SESSIONS OPENED" 
          session.set_access_token(DROPCONFIG['access_token'], DROPCONFIG['access_token_secret']);
          logger.debug "BeforeDropboxclient"
          client = DropboxClient.new(session, 'dropbox')